# Issue in selecting 'Add' / 'Cancel' through Selenium Webdriver on Chrome extension dialog

Tags: google-chrome-extension, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to automate the process of adding Chrome extension through `Selenium Webdriver`. There comes a dialog that asks user to click 'Add' to add extension. I am facing issue in this part.

Here are the things that I've **tried but did not work :**

1. Trying to treat it as 'Alert' and accepting it.
2. Trying to get its properties but as it is not part of web page we can not see its properties. its chrome's in-build dialog.
3. Keyboard simulator (hitting Enter)

I know we can use `AutoIt` but don't want to integrate it with framework just for single issue. Is there any other way you folks can suggest. One workaround that I an thinking if we can get a global keyboard shortcut to select 'Add' on the chrome extension dialog.

Comment: Did you try using the Robot class incase you are using Java?

Comment: No. Actually I am looking for ways in existing selenium libraries or workarounds. Robot or AutoIT both can do it. But we cant extend our framework with Robot/AutoIt for a single issue.

Comment: This dialog is also here for security issue. It's explicitly here for the user to see it. I'm not sure why you want to bypass it.

Comment: I dont want to bypass it. I want to click on 'Add' through Selenium Webdriver code